# Resetting a quiz with reset button

Tags: javascript, html

new to stack overflow here. My question is what I might have done wrong with this quiz reset button? I have it set so that if the reset button is clicked at the end of the quiz, the quiz should return to the first question. However, the button is doing nothing. I was thinking I may have variable scope issues but I tried to accommodate for that and I still can't get the reset button to work. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
   <title>Hello...</title>

</head>

<body>
   <h1 id="theTitle" class="highlight summer">BATMAN QUIZ!</h1>

   <div id="mainContent">
      <div id="question">
      </div>
      <div id="choices">
         <input type="radio" name="choices" /><label id="choice1" class="radios"></label></br>
         <input type="radio" name="choices" /><label id="choice2" class="radios"></label></br>
         <input type="radio" name="choices" /><label id="choice3" class="radios"></label></br>
         <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" /></br>
         <input type="submit" class="hidden" id="nextButton" value="Next Question" />
      </div>

      <div class="hidden" id="answer">
      </div>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
   display:none;
}

.visible{
   display:inline;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var questionArray = [
   ["What is Batman's first name?", "Bruce Wayne"],
   ["What city does Batman live in?", "Gotham"],
   ["What is Commisioner Gordon's daughter's name?", "Barbara"]
];

var choicesArray = [
   ["Bruce Wayne", "Clark Kent", "Charles Xavier"],
   ["Metropolis", "Starling City", "Gotham"],
   ["Helen", "Barbara", "Jean"]
]

i = 0;
theQuiz(i);

function theQuiz(i) {
   if (i < questionArray.length) {
      var score = 0;

      document.querySelector("#question").textContent = questionArray[i][0];
      document.querySelector("#answer").textContent = "The correct answer is: " + questionArray[i][1];

      document.querySelector("#choice1").textContent = choicesArray[i][0];
      document.querySelector("#choice2").textContent = choicesArray[i][1];
      document.querySelector("#choice3").textContent = choicesArray[i][2];

      var answer = document.querySelector("#answer");

      var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submitButton")
      submitButton.addEventListener("click", showAnswer, false);

      var nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextButton")
      nextButton.addEventListener("click", nextQuestion, false);

      function showAnswer() {
         answer.classList.add("visible");
         nextButton.classList.add("visible");
      };

      function nextQuestion() {
         answer.classList.remove("visible");
         nextButton.classList.remove("visible");
         i++;
         theQuiz(i);
      };

   } else {

      document.body.textContent = "Game Over!";
      var restartButton = document.createElement("input")
      restartButton.type = "submit";
      restartButton.value = "Play Again!"
      document.body.appendChild(restartButton);
      i=0;
      theQuiz(i);
      restartButton.addEventListener("click", resetGame, true);
      function resetGame() {
         i = 0;
         theQuiz(0);
      };

   }
};
```

Comment: would an `<input type="reset">` work for you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: @JaromandaX wouldn't that just reset the form though? I was thinking more of total reset to the initial question but I can't get it to go back to the original question

Comment: Sorry. Didn't read the question very well did I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refresh the whole page: `location.reload();`

If you want to reset just where you are at on the quiz:

Wrap the whole quiz in a `<form>` and add this `<input type='reset'>` that's it.
Added and changed the following:

#### Required

- `button#fullReset` and `EventListener`added
- `#mainContent` into a `<form>`
- `<input type='reset'>`added

#### Recommended

- `#choices` to a `<fieldset>`
- `#theTitle` inside `<legend>`
- `#answer` into a `<input type='hidden'>`

#### Specification

- id on `<label>` are useless, follow this pattern:

  ```
    <label for='rad1'>Radio 1</label>
    <input id='rad1' name='rads'>
  ```
- Either `<br>` or `<br/>` **never** `</br>`

#### SNIPPET

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello...</title>

</head>

<body>


  <form id="mainContent">

    <fieldset id="choices">
      <legend>
        <h1 id="theTitle" class="highlight summer">BATMAN QUIZ!</h1>
      </legend>
      <input type="radio" name="choices" />
      <label id="choice1" class="radios"></label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="choices" />
      <label id="choice2" class="radios"></label>
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="choices" />
      <label id="choice3" class="radios"></label>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
      <br>
      <input type="submit" class="hidden" id="nextButton" value="Next Question" />


      <input type="hidden" id="answer">
      <input type='reset'>
      <button id='fullReset'>Full Reset</button>

    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <script>
    var fullReset = document.getElementById('fullReset');

    fullReset.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      location.reload();
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```